# Trigger in restricting files based on file type in Chatter feed, Email Message and attachment?

Tags: apex, trigger

Please suggest if there is any way to restrict files without using trigger. If trigger is the only way then please review the below code and guide me to achieve this which is currently not working.

Trigger code for Chatter File restriction :

```
trigger FilterFileFormate on ContentVersion (after insert) {
    for (ContentVersion cv : Trigger.new) {
        // Origin is 'H' for Chatter files, 'C' for Content documents
        // Leave out the test for Origin if you want to cover both
        if (cv.Origin == 'H' && cv.FileType == 'EXE') {
            cv.addError('EXE files are not allowed to upload..!');
        }
    }
}
```

Modified the code as suggested :
**Code 2 :**

```
trigger RestrictFilesOnFeedItems on FeedItem (after insert) {
    for(FeedItem fi : trigger.new){
        if(fi.type == 'ContentPost' && (fi.RelatedRecordId.FileType =='EXE' || fi.RelatedRecordId.FileType=='HTML' || fi.RelatedRecordId.FileType=='EDI')){

            fi.addError('Executable files, HTML & EDI file formats are not allowed to insert');
            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `FeedItem` trigger to `AfterInsert`.

`type` and many other fields don't get populated in the before trigger. So if you want to access the properties, after trigger is what you want.

If you want to check for the extension type of the file, use the `RelatedRecordId` field of `FeedItem`. The Id will be of `ContentVersion` which holds the fields such as `fileExtension` and `fileType`.

**UPDATE:**

Simply doing a `fi.RelatedRecordId.FileType =='EXE'` wont help because  fi.RelatedRecordId is just an ID field, not a relation.

You will have to fetch all the RelatedRecordId for all record whose fi.type == 'ContentPost'.

```
Map<Id, FeedItem> contentversionIdToFeedItemMap = new Map<Id, FeedItem>();
for(FeedItem fi : trigger.new){
if(fi.type == 'ContentPost')
    contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.put(fi.RelatedRecordId, fi);
}
```

Now fire a query to fetch all the ContentVersion records with FieldType field and addError if it satisfies your condition.

```
for(ContentVersion cv : [SELECT Id, FileExtension,FileType FROM ContentVersion where Id IN :contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.keySet()])
{
    if(cv.FileType =='EXE' || cv.FileType=='HTML')
    {
        contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.get(cv.Id).addError('You can not add this type of file');
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not allowing me to proceed with fi.RelatedRecordId.FileType =='EXE', Please correct me to restrict it on filetype. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation why it was not working and how it will work.